%whos command not listing variable starting with _
On a jupyter notebook, I am trying
a = 10
b = 20
_w = 90

then when trying %whos, I only get:
Variable   Type    Data/Info
----------------------------
a          int     10
b          int     20

Why does the variable name starting with _ not appear in the list of variables?

Because those are private by convention.
